# Finding the nodes in the source and sink side of a min-cut

Tags: network-flow, minimum-cuts, ford-fulkerson

We are learning of the Ford-Fulkerson Algorithm for max-flow/min-cut, and I have been wondering of the following question:

How do we exactly find which nodes are on the "sink" side of the min-cut produced using the  algorithm?

I have read here
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-cut-in-a-directed-graph/
that all nodes reachable from the source node on the final residual graph using a BFS/DFS are on one side of the min-cut.

Then, will all nodes not reachable from the source node on the final residual graph be on the other side of the min cut? Is there any way of finding these nodes using a search algorithm of some sort - for example, reversing the edges of the final residual graph and running a BFS/DFS on the sink node?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove that any minimal s-t-cut results in two connected components, the one with s in, and the one with t in. Call them S and T.

Then the actual cut is all the edges that go from S to T.